# Duplicate content in views

Tags: views, media

I implemented the media browser module for image uploading and changed one of the image fields to utilise the media browser for a particular content type. After which, the views which displays a list of that particular content type is showing duplicate content.

After googling I found some one who had a similar problem to mine, however, I don't understand how he solved his problem. https://drupal.org/node/1764042

I would greatly appreciate any help given.
Thanks a lot.

Update:
Figured out the problem. I was using a file:usage relationship to generate the path url for rewriting the output. Hence having multiple files linked to that node would generate multiple views.

Comment: Post your answer separately and accept it as a solution to own question. That way the solution will be clear for others with the same problem.

Comment: Please post your answer separately and don't include the your answer in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only post an answer to my own question after 8 hours. Will transfer the answer into a proper answer once I am able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I was using a file:usage relationship to generate the path url for rewriting the output. Hence having multiple files linked to that node would generate multiple views.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you are have applied filters on any date field. I had similar problem, try this, in Views Advanced Settings under OTHER options, select "Query Setting" and check "Distinct" option.